# How do I access which QCheckBox is checked in PySide2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I am developing a GUI in PySide2, in which I am displaying a QCheckBoxes in a QScrollArea using a loop, and I want to access those checkboxes which are checked by the user.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = data

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.grid.addWidget(button)

    def onButton(self):
        row = 1
        for item in self.data:
            checkBox_measurement = QCheckBox(item)
            self.grid.addWidget(checkBox_measurement, row, 0)

            line = QtWidgets.QFrame()
            line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
            self.grid.addWidget(line, row+1, 0, 1, 2)
            row += 2
data = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3' , 'Title 4', 'Title 5', 'Title 6' ,'Title 7', 'Title 8', 'Title 9' ]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow(data)
    myWindow.resize(500, 300)
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This is the code which create checkboxes in my window, how would I know that which checkboxes are checked by user

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Add `ChkBoxes = {}` and change `ChkBoxes[Row] = QCheckBox(Item)` and change `self.Grid.addWidget(ChkBoxes[Row], Row, 0)`  then you can reference each Check box easily by simply using the Row you placed it in or by getting the Row of the the selected item

Comment: @S.Nick now check please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = data

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.grid.addWidget(button)

    def onButton(self):
        row = 1
        for item in self.data:
            checkBox_measurement = QCheckBox(item)
            checkBox_measurement.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)     # +

            self.grid.addWidget(checkBox_measurement, row, 0)

            line = QtWidgets.QFrame()
            line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
            self.grid.addWidget(line, row+1, 0, 1, 2)
            row += 2


    def clickBox(self, state):                                           # +
        print(state, self.sender().text())                               # +


data = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3' , 'Title 4', 'Title 5', 'Title 6' ,'Title 7', 'Title 8', 'Title 9' ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow(data)
    myWindow.resize(500, 300)
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much It solved my problem. Can you guide me where I can learn pyside or pyqt without using qt designer

Comment: @Haider  Read to start `http://zetcode.com/` . If my answer helped you, do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: I correct it but it would not be show because my reputations are less then

Comment: @Haider   I added you a reputation :)